# Transaction has 100 confirmations but it's not being shown in my Exodus wallet

Tags: lost-transactions, exodus

I have sent a transaction to my Exodus wallet but it isn't being shown there. The transaction now has more than 100 confirmations. What does mean when it has a lot of confirmations but doesn't show up? What I can do to return it? Is there anything can I do ?

Comment: Can you provide a receiving address the funds are confirmed at, or a tx ID? If the tx is confirmed (100+ blocks deep), and Exodus is showing you the correct receiving address (that the funds have been confirmed at), then it sounds like the Exodus wallet is not properly in sync with the network.

Comment: address: 1UyoYU6kTD7uuZK6vXEpNiVNN66X9WNj6                                       actually Exodus show me nothing, there is no transaction.

Comment: the address indeed shows funds, but your wallet doesn't. So the link between the private key and the address is broken. There is no way to "calculate" a link between these two, otherwise the entire bitcoin system would be broken. So you might need to double check, what addresses are really included in your wallet, and compare them one by one. Maybe there was a typo, when providing the address to the sender? Also you may ask the person you sent the funds to, if it is really "his" address...

Comment: I can't see the transaction on exodus wallet to compare it. can I use this address to send it to another wallet or it may cause another problem ?

Answer (score 1):

The address 1UyoY... is currently funded, so the transaction did indeed go through.

If Exodus wallet shows you 1UyoY.. as a receiving address but no current balance, then your wallet is not in sync with the network.

If you cannot get Exodus wallet to sync with the network properly, you could try exporting the seed phrase / private key from Exodus and import it into some other wallet software.

Bottom line: the bitcoin are sitting at that address, so if you have the private key to that address, you just need to find some software that will properly sync with the network so that you can spend the coins.

Comment: thank you. I have a recovery phrase, is that what you mean ? can you please tell me for example which software I can use to do that ? I want to say also when I get the receiving address from Exodus nothing registered after that. the wallet is empty. no funds and no receiving transactions registered.